# SP 2013 - My Sites and personal time zone settings

Tags: sharepoint-server

Since we don't use My Sites in our current environment can SharePoint users use personal settings for their time zone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need go to Edit User Profile page in Central Administration(CA). And then set "Choose your settings" to "Always use my personal settings", and "Use language and regional settings" must be checked.

[image]

And then login in site using this user and go to the page below to check the Time Zone settings.

```
http://sp2013/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx?type=user
```

[image]